# Why @Html.AntiForgeryToken() returns null?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have configured my web asp.net mvc app in iis on our server. after app starts the an exception occurs such below:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 10: {
Line 11:     <div class="form-horizontal">
Line 12:         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  <-- here
```

i've checked the MachineKey (in the web.config) of the app in iis which is :

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
```

I can't figure out what is the problem!

**Update:**

also, I checked the session,But it's not null. I got `Session.SessionID` in a razor and I got a valid value (`hutqqygxwbvvwaerztvamf1n`).

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar error.  A working form started to fail on the @html.AntiForgeryToken().

It turned out to be one of the lines of html I added:

<a href=# onclick="@(Html.Raw(String.Format("EditCrops({0})",@ViewBag.ContactId)))">Alternate Contacts

When I commented out this line of html, it worked again.